# collide with the hand to trigger feedback

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision, eventtrigger

I am beginner in unity 3d programming, I have a project to integrate my feedback device with the virtual reality software (unity3d free version). I use leap motion to make my hand appear on the unity3d, and when the object (ball) touch the hand, it will trigger the feedback device to send the information.

I built the dll library for my feedback device, I have tried in c# and working.

I use onCollisionEnter to trigger the event. Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 

public class trigger : MonoBehaviour {  
[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint="tens_init")]
public static extern int tens_init ([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string port);
[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_shutdown")]
public static extern void tens_shutdown();

[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_settarget")]
public static extern int tens_settarget(byte id);

 [DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_write")]
 public static extern int tens_write([MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string buf, int count);

[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_enable")]
 public static extern int tens_enable(byte supply_on, byte bridge_on);

 [DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_power")]
public static extern int tens_power(byte power);

[DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_freq")]
public static extern int tens_freq(byte freq);

 [DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_chargerate")]
 public static extern int tens_chargerate(byte rate);

 [DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_writeconfig")]
 public static extern int tens_writeconfig();

 [DllImport("tensLibs.dll", EntryPoint = "tens_envs")]
public static extern int tens_envs(byte distance);

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision col) {

    if (col.gameObject.name == "bone1" || col.gameObject.name == "bone2" || col.gameObject.name == "bone3" || col.gameObject.name == "palm") {

         if (tens_init("COM8") == 1){
             Debug.Log ("Com 8 is initiated"); }
        else {
            Debug.Log ("Com 8 does not exists"); }


        tens_settarget(0); //send to device 0
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
         tens_envs(150); //send value
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        tens_shutdown(); //close the com
     }

     }
```

The problem is, when I touch the ball, the event just showing me that the tens_init is working by appearing `Com 8 is initiated` but the rest of the program are not execute (I think because do not work).

Do I make mistake with the script?

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in unity you don't use the `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(...)` syntax, you need to look into `yield waitforseconds`

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Comment: how about if I want set the delay less than 1 second, let say 0.01 second?

Comment: waitforseconds takes a float as a parameter, so you should be able to do small numbers, although you might get into some interesting situations with sufficiently small numbers (i.e. smaller than seconds per frame)... if you want to skip a frame you just need `yield;`

Comment: there is error occur when I add yield waitforSecond, the error is "the body of trigger.OnCollisionEnter cannot be an iterator block because the void is not an iterator interface type"

Comment: ah, you'll need to put the yield code into a coroutine which is called from the OnCollisionEnter. The collision is the "trigger" event which started the coroutine running, it then handles the waiting/processing over time... you can't have the "trigger" waiting, it's a one shot affair.